# Jquery get options with out default option

Tags: jquery

I have following select element.

```
<select id="names" name="name">
   <option value="">Please select</option>
   <option value="1">Homba</option>
   <option value="2">Bamba</option>
</select>
```

I want to get only

```
<option value="1">Homba</option>
<option value="2">Bamba</option>
```

How can i do it? I want option html elements. not jquery object. I will make another select element using that options.

Comment: what do you mean ? Is a server generating the select options for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#names option[value!=""]')` should return a jQuery object with all option elements that do not have `value=""`.

**UPDATE**

If you must have **only** the `option` elements, then:

```
var myOptions = jQuery.makeArray($('#names option[value!=""]').clone());
```

will return an array of `option` elements copied from `<select id="names" name="name">` that do not have `value=""` (and store it in a variable called `myOptions`).

If, on the other hand, you want to make another `select` element with the matched options, **the jQuery object that is returned is more useful**:

```
var newSelect = $('<select />').append($('#names option[value!=""]').clone());
```

The above statement copies the `option` elements into a new `select` element and returns a jQuery object which is stored in the `newSelect` variable and can be appended to the DOM where ever you like.

Here's a fiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/3SUy7/

Comment: But i want option elements. not object

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select all options that have some non-empty value:

```
$("option[value!='']")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#names option[value='']").remove();
```

This will remove the first option

To iterate

```
$("#names > option").each(function() {
    if( this.value != "")
        //do some thing
});
```

to select

```
   $("#names option[value!='']")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#names option[value!='']")
```

or

```
jQuery("#names :not(option[value=''])")
```

This will select all options except the one without value